# the best way to insert an element in the right place

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am implementing a jquery function which is able to insert a div in the right place depending on the existing dom structure

The case of existing dom structure are the following

```
<!-- case 1 -->
<div class='container'>
   <div class='foo'></div>
   <div class='bar'>last bar</div>
   <div class='bar'>some bar</div>
   <div class='bar'>first bar</div>
</div>

<!-- case 2 -->
<div class='container'>
   <div class='bar'>last bar</div>
   <div class='bar'>some bar</div>
   <div class='bar'>first bar</div>
</div>


<!-- case 3 -->
<div class='container'>
</div>
```

In every 3 cases, it should add a new `<div class='bar'></div>` inside container but before the first `<div class='bar'></div>`

here is the code which works for the case 1 and 2 but not for the 3.

```
var last_bar = $('<div>').addClass('bar').text('last bar');
$($('.container').find('.bar')[0]).prepend(last_bar)​;
```

​

Any hints how to make this code more general?

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/3wFda/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just me, but I like to wrap things in new functions like this...

```
$.fn.addBar = function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        var $last_bar = $('<div>').addClass('bar').text('last bar');
        if ($(this).find(".bar").length == 0) {
            $(this).append($last_bar);
        } else {
            $(this).find('.bar:first').prepend($last_bar); 
        }
    });
};
```

Then you just call it like this...

```
​$(".container").addBar();​​​​​
```

Here's an updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3wFda/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var last_bar = $('<div>').addClass('bar').text('last bar');
$($('.container').find('.bar')[0] || $('.container')).prepend(last_bar);​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container').find('.bar:first').prepend(...)
```

**EDIT** your Case 3 requires some extra work.

```
var $c = $('.container');
if($c.contains('.bar').length) {
    $c.find('.bar:first').prepend(...)
} else {
    $c.append(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead,

```
var last_bar = $('<div>').addClass('bar').text('last bar');
$('.container .bar:eq(0), .container:empty').prepend(last_bar);​
```